# Мне накручивают клики по рекламе? Помогите определить, более 1000 кликов в сутки

Tags: google-play, admob

Пишу, так как боюсь что меня заблокируют в AdMob.

Обычно в среднем у меня в день **25000** просмотров рекламы и **250 кликов**, за вчера было **12,2 $** т.е. на 100 просмотров 1 клик, сегодня утром (8:00) проснулся, смотрю AdSense и вижу 40000 просмотров и 350 кликов,

На данный момент уже 125 тысяч просмотров рекламы и 1000 кликов, при этом всего **13,69 $**...

Что это может быть? Кто-то дудосит мою рекламу в игре? Зачем это кому-то нужно, а если нет, то почему с 1000 кликов всего 13 долларов, если вчера было с 250 кликов - 12 долларов.....

Установок игры в день 3200, за сегодня статистика примерно такая, как и вчера (3200 в день).

Откуда идут просмотры/клики рекламы - не понятно.

**Кто сталкивался? Могут ли меня заблокировать из-за таких недоброжелателей?**